# Prevent dragging of child element within a draggable element

Tags: html

I have an element that I want to be able to drag, but I have elements inside of it that I don't want to be able to drag. I'm hoping there is a simple answer without (a lot of) jQuery.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<style>
  .a {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }

  .b{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
  }
</style>
  <body>
    <div class="a" draggable="true">
      <span>I can drag this!</span>
      <div class="b" draggable="false">
        I can drag this as well, but I don't want to.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xto7lPO32TRVScewJkS9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this question is still relevant, but I found a way to solve your problem like this:

```
  <body>
    <div class="a" draggable="true">
      <span>I can drag this!</span>
      <div class="b" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.preventDefault()">
        I can drag this as well, but I don't want to.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Seems a little hacky, but it does the trick. I haven't found any other way to solve this. Hope it helps you.

Cheers
Sam

Comment: Works for preventing the div child to be dragged, but for text input it also causes the text to not be able to be selected. Never mind you set draggable to "true" or "false on the child div.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is availlable in this code (that allows touch with finger too) :

```
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.is-draggable');

[].forEach.call(draggables, function (el) {
    var startX, startY, initialX, initialY,
        auth = function (target) {
            var notDraggables = el.querySelectorAll('.is-not-draggable');

            return [].filter.call(notDraggables, function (element) {
                return target !== element;
            }).length > 0;
        };

    function move(gesture) {
        var deltaGestureX = gesture.clientX - initialX,
            deltaGestureY = gesture.clientY - initialY,
            deltaPositionX = startX + deltaGestureX,
            deltaPositionY = startY + deltaGestureY,
            limitX = parseInt(window.innerWidth - el.clientWidth, 10),
            limitY = parseInt(window.innerHeight - el.clientHeight, 10);

        if (deltaPositionY <= 0) {
            el.style.top = '0px';
        } else if (deltaPositionY >= limitY) {
            el.style.top = limitY + 'px';
        } else {
            el.style.top = startY + deltaGestureY + 'px';
        }

        if (deltaPositionX <= 0) {
            el.style.left = '0px';
        } else if (deltaPositionX >= limitX) {
            el.style.left = limitX + 'px';
        } else {
            el.style.left = startX + deltaGestureX + 'px';
        }

        return false;
    }

    function mousemove(e) {
        move(e);
    }

    function mouseup() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
    }

    function touchmove(e) {
        move(e.touches[0]);
    }

    function touchend() {
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', touchmove);
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', touchend);
    }

    el.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        if (auth(e.target)) {
            startX = el.offsetLeft;
            startY = el.offsetTop;
            initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
            initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove);
            document.addEventListener('touchend', touchend);
        }
    });

    el.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        if (auth(e.target)) {
            startX = el.offsetLeft;
            startY = el.offsetTop;
            initialX = e.clientX;
            initialY = e.clientY;
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

See demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/d6wVpTDcGDxLHAwkAVgD?p=preview